# ¿Cómo accedo a un array en otro método?

Tags: javascript, poo, método

estoy aprendiendo POO con javascript y para practicar quise codificar un ejercicio que ya había hecho pero ahora con POO, solo que me topé con que no sé cómo usar el array alumnos que creé en el método asignarNombres() en el método tomarAsistencia(), lo cual me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me había ocurrido crear el array en el constructor pero me daba undefined al momento de querer usarlo.

```
<script>
'use strict'
class Salon {
    constructor(cantidadAlumnos, asistencia) {
        this.cantidadAlumnos = cantidadAlumnos;
        this.asistencia = asistencia;
    }

    static contarAlumnos() {
        this.cantidadAlumnos = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuántos alumnos hay?'));
    }

    static asignarNombres() {
        let alumnos = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cantidadAlumnos; i++) {
            alumnos[i] = [prompt('Nombre del alumno ' + (i + 1)), 0];
        }
    }

    static tomarAsistencia() {
        for (let alumno in alumnos) {
            let asistencia = prompt(`¿Está presente ${alumnos[alumno][0]}?`);
            if (asistencia === 'p' || asistencia === 'P') {
                alumnos[alumno][1]++;
            }
        }
    }

    static mostrarAsistencias() {
        for (let alumno in alumnos) {
            document.write(`
        ${this.alumnos[alumno][0]}<br>
        Asistencias: ${alumnos[alumno][1]}<br>
        Inasistencias: 5 - ${alumnos[alumno[1]]}<br>
        `);
            if (alumnos[alumno][1] < 6) {
                document.write('Reprobado por inasistencias<br><br>');
            } else {
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    }
}

Salon.contarAlumnos();
Salon.asignarNombres();
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Salon.tomarAsistencia();
}
Salon.mostrarAsistencia();
```

De antemano, muchas gracias c:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comenté en la respuesta de @Triby, aparte de resolver el problema de meter el array de alumnos en el constructor, esto está muy lejos de ser POO. Por varios motivos:

- los métodos actuales que se llaman en el constructor de la clase no hacen más que estorbar ahí, cada vez que se instancie la clase saltarán esos métodos;
- además una clase que te pregunte lo que ella debería darte (en el caso del total de alumnos) no tiene ninguna utilidad. Para saber la cantidad de alumnos en el Salón habría que contar la cantidad de elementos en el array de alumnos.
- El método `asignarNombres` también es cuestionable. En un contexto habitual se llenaría un array de alumnos desde fuera y en la clase podría quedar un método para actualizar algún alumno si hiciera falta.
- Se supone que debería haber una clase `Alumno` para poder usar sus métodos y sacar el mayor provecho a la POO.

Este sería un modelo básico de tu clase con algunas mejoras que ya apuntan a lo que propone la POO.

```js
/*Clase Alumno*/
class Alumno {
  constructor(nombre, edad) {
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._edad = edad;
    this.asistencias = 0;
  }

  set nombre(nombre) {
    this._nombre = nombre;
  }

  get nombre() {
    return this._nombre;
  }

  toString() {
    return `${this._nombre} \t ${this._edad} \t ${this.asistencias}`;

  }
}



/*Clase Salon*/
class Salon {
  constructor(alumnos) {
    this.alumnos = alumnos;
  }

  contarAlumnos() {
    /*Simplemente contamos al erray*/
    return this.alumnos.length;
  }

  listarAlumnos() {
    /*Nótese que aquí usamos el método toString de la clase Alumno*/
    let s = "";

    this.alumnos.forEach(function(obj){
        s+=obj.toString()+'\n';
    }); 
    return s;
  }

  updateAlumno(index, nombre) {
    this.alumnos[index].nombre = nombre;
  }

  addAlumno(alumno) {
    this.alumnos.push(alumno);
  }

  tomarAsistencia() {
      this.alumnos.forEach(function(obj){

//    for (var key in lstAlumnos) {
//      var mItem = this.alumnos[key];
      let s = prompt(`¿Está presente ${obj.nombre}?`);
      if (s.toUpperCase() === 'P') {
        obj.asistencias++;
      }
    });
  }

  /*No me meto con este método, entendiendo lo otro podrás resolverlo de la mejor manera*/
  static mostrarAsistencias(alumnos) {
    for (let alumno in alumnos) {
      document.write(`
        ${alumnos[alumno][0]}<br>
        Asistencias: ${alumnos[alumno][1]}<br>
        Inasistencias: 5 - ${alumnos[alumno][1]}<br>
        `);
      if (alumnos[alumno][1] < 6) {
        document.write('Reprobado por inasistencias<br><br>');
      } else {
        document.write('<br>');
      }
    }
  }
}

/*Creamos una lista de alumnos*/
let lstAlumnos = [new Alumno('Pedro', 20), new Alumno('Marta', 22)];

/*Se la pasamos al constructor de Salon*/
let mSalon = new Salon(lstAlumnos);
console.log(`Total de alumnos: ${mSalon.contarAlumnos()}`);
console.log('Lista de alumnos inicial: ');
console.log(mSalon.listarAlumnos());

/*Cambiamos el nombre de uno*/
mSalon.updateAlumno(0, 'Peter*');
mSalon.tomarAsistencia();

console.log('Lista con asistencia y nombre de Pedro cambiado: ');

console.log(mSalon.listarAlumnos());

/*Llegó un nuevo alumno*/
mSalon.addAlumno(new Alumno('Carla',20));
mSalon.tomarAsistencia();
console.log('Lista actualizada: ');

console.log(mSalon.listarAlumnos());
```

Comment: Interesante propuesta, pero no me convence del todo, porque hay conceptos que solo expresas y no explicas si son parte de un paradigma o patrón de desarrollo, por ejemplo: ¿Es obligatoria la clase `Alumno` o solo _"se supone"_ que debería existir y por qué?. Aparte, no entiendo para qué crear la propiedad `this.alumnos` cuando, en los métodos de la clase, acceder a la variable global `lstAlumnos`, deberías usar directamente la propiedad.

Comment: ¿Por qué usar ciclos `for()`? Los arreglos son objetos y tienen métodos específicos como `.forEach()`. ¿Por qué declaras la variable del ciclo con `var` en lugar de `let`? Dependiendo del contexto, este punto podría ser realmente importante.

Comment: @Triby, agradezco tus comentarios. Tienes razón en lo que dices sobre el `forEach` y sobre el uso de `lstAlumnos` en vez de usar la variable de clase, he corregido ambas cosas... ayer era tarde y escribí la respuesta un poco a la carrera. Sobre lo de usar una clase `Alumno` o no es opcional, pero si de lo que se trata es de implementar POO no cabe duda de que una entidad como `Alumno` debería tener su propia clase. En este ejemplo sencillo, la utilidad del método `toString()` demuestra ya la comodidad de trabajar con objetos. Pensemos en cosas más complejas, como tener que mantener ...

Comment: ... un estado de asistencias por `Salon`, o generar un record de notas en diferentes cursos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder tener disponible el arreglo de alumnos, debes declararlos como propiedad de la clase, pero, si vas a manejar [métodos estáticos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) no van a estar asociados a la instancia de la clase y, por lo tanto, deberás proporcionar el arreglo como parámetro.

Es importante que definas cómo vas a trabajar la clase, porque se debe instanciar anteponiendo `new`, por ejemplo: `let salon = new Salon();`; es la única forma de que las propiedades puedan usarse dentro de los métodos *no-estáticos* sin tener que enviarlas como parámetros.

En este ejemplo dejé como estático solo el método para mostrar asistencias

```js
'use strict'
class Salon {
    constructor() {
        // Inicializar alumnos
        this.alumnos = [];
        this.contarAlumnos();
        this.asignarNombres();
    }

    contarAlumnos() {
        // Crear propiedad con cantidad de alumnos
        this.cantidadAlumnos = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuántos alumnos hay?'));
    }

    asignarNombres() {
        // Actualizar arreglo de alumnos
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cantidadAlumnos; i++) {
            let nombre = prompt('Nombre del alumno ' + (i + 1));
            this.alumnos.push([nombre, 0]);
        }
    }

    tomarAsistencia() {
        for (let alumno in this.alumnos) {
            let asistencia = prompt(`¿Está presente ${this.alumnos[alumno][0]}?`);
            if (asistencia === 'p' || asistencia === 'P') {
                this.alumnos[alumno][1]++;
            }
        }
    }

    static mostrarAsistencias(alumnos) {
        for (let alumno in alumnos) {
            document.write(`
        ${alumnos[alumno][0]}<br>
        Asistencias: ${alumnos[alumno][1]}<br>
        Inasistencias: 5 - ${alumnos[alumno][1]}<br>
        `);
            if (alumnos[alumno][1] < 6) {
                document.write('Reprobado por inasistencias<br><br>');
            } else {
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    }
}

// Crear instancia de clase
let salon = new Salon();
/*
// Estos dos ya se hacen desde el constructor, no es necesario ejecutarlos nuevamente
// salon.contarAlumnos();
// salon.asignarNombres();
*/
// Ejecutar método no estático usando el nombre de la instancia
salon.tomarAsistencia()

// Ejecutar método estático usando el nombre de la clase
// Se debe enviar parámetro al método estático
Salon.mostrarAsistencias(salon.alumnos);
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, voy a analizar el código para entenderlo bien

Comment: Aparte de resolver el problema de meter el array de `alumnos` en el constructor, esto está muy lejos de ser POO. Por varios motivos: los métodos que se llaman en el constructor de la clase no hacen más que estorbar ahí, cada vez que se instancie la clase saltarán esos métodos; además una clase que te pregunte lo que ella debería darte no tiene ninguna utilidad, para saber la cantidad de alumnos en el Salón habría que contar la cantidad de elementos en el array de alumnos. El método asignarNombres también es cuestionable. En un contexto habitual se llenaría un array de alumnos desde fuera ...

Comment: ... de la clase y se pasaría al constructor ese array con los alumnos. No quita que tengas un setter por si luego quieres agregar un alumno más. Hay más cosas, pero ya entraríamos en otro terreno. Solamente quiero señalar esas cosas básicas que saltan a la vista y que hacen que esa clase esté bastante lejos de lo que propone la POO.

Comment: @A.Cedano, muy respetable tu opinión, solo me limité a adaptar su ejemplo y comentar cómo puede crear propiedades para usarlas en los diferentes métodos. Realmente me interesaría ver una propuesta de tu parte, donde expliques cada uno de los puntos expuestos y poder llevarme hoy un buen aprendizaje.